# Publish message to pubsub on google group event change

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-groups, google-groups-api

I want send notification to Pubsub If any user in google group gets suspended or removed it should send notification to pubsub , I want to know how I can achieve this , I cannot found any proper documentation for it , please suggest me how to do it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/push